# Plotting Two Histograms. Why can't one have kde while other not have it?

Tags: python, data-visualization, seaborn, histogram

So I was going through the Kaggle Data Visualization Micro Course, and I reached the lesson on plotting histograms.
So the excercise asked to plot two histograms and I did that and it worked, but if I add kde = False on one of the plots, only that plot will be visible, the other plot isn't displayed:

```
           `sns.distplot(a = cancer_b_data['Area (mean)'], kde = False) 
            sns.distplot(a = cancer_m_data['Area (mean)'])  `
```

Don't know how stupid I sound, but any clarification would help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default `kde=True` the kde is normalized such that the area under the curve is one. To go together in the same plot, the histogram will also be normalized such that the complete area of all bars sums to one.

With `kde=False`, the default histogram will show the frequency (the count of each bin), which are much larger numbers. If you display both inside the same plot with the same axes, the normalized histogram will not disappear, but be very small. With the zoom tool you can verify that it still is there. To see both with the same size, `sns.distplot(..., kde=False, norm_hist=True)` can be used

You'll note that the two histogram don't use the same bin boundaries. These boundaries are calculated using the number of samples and the minimum and maximum of the individual sets of samples.

To really compare two histograms, explicit bins can be set, so both use the same bin boundaries.

The following code and plot compares the 3 different ways to compare the histograms:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x1 = np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
x2 = np.random.randn(100).cumsum()
fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(ncols=3, figsize=(15, 4))

sns.distplot(a=x1, kde=False, ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(a=x2, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_title('one histogram without kde')

sns.distplot(a=x1, kde=False, norm_hist=True, ax=ax2)
sns.distplot(a=x2, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('setting norm_hist=True')

xmin = min(x1.min(), x2.min())
xmax = max(x1.max(), x2.max())
bins = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 11)
sns.distplot(a=x1, kde=False, norm_hist=True, bins=bins, ax=ax3)
sns.distplot(a=x2, bins=bins, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_title('using the same bins')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: comparing 3 histograms]